# Fill empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset where some of the rows are not placed in the right column. For example

data:

```
#DataFrame
data = {'Status': ['Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active','Active', 'Active'],
        'Name': ['Tom', ' ', 'krish', ' ',  'Jack', 'Lisa'],
        'Email': ['test@gmail.com', ' ',  'test@gmail.com', ' ', 'test@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com'],
        'Name2': [' ', 'John', ' ', 'Tim', ' ', ' '],
        'Email2':[' ', 'test@gmail.com', ' ', 'test@gmail.com', ' ', ' ']}

#Print DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

In this case, the column 'Name' and 'email' has some empty spaces because they were placed in the a new column called 'name2' and 'email2'

I would like to see if I can fill the empty spaces with the actual name and email that were misplaced in different columns.

I was trying to do some research but I did not find any significant information or I do not know if this is possible.

actual dataset:

```
Status  Name  Email          Name2      Email2 
Active  Tom   t@gmail.com  
Active                       Tim        t@gmail.com
Active  Tom   t@gmail.com 
Active                       Tim        t@gmail.com
```

Expected result

```
Name2   Name  Email2 
Active  Tom   t@gmail.com  
Active  Tim   t@gmail.com
Active  Tom   t@gmail.com 
Active  Tom   t@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This option is faster than all other current answers, as per the `timeit` comparison at the bottom.
- Select the appropriate columns into separate dataframes with [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), combine the dataframes with [`.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and sort the index.

  - Boolean indexing is vectorized and much faster than using `.apply`.
- Empty cells are specified in the OP with `' '`, which is used in `df.Name.ne(' ')` to skip rows with that value.

  - If the empty spaces are `np.nan`, then do `~df.Name.isna()` instead of `df.Name.ne(' ')`.
  - Use `df = df.replace('\\s+', '', regex=True)` if the empty strings are of different or indeterminate length, and change `.ne(' ')` to  `.ne('')`.
- `.copy()` can be dropped if it doesn't result in `SettingwithCopyWarning`, which it didn't during testing.

```py
# select Status and the columns without numbers
df1 = df.loc[df.Name.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name', 'Email']].copy()

# select Status and the columns with 2; rename the columns with 2
df2 = df.loc[df.Name2.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name2', 'Email2']].copy().rename({'Name2': 'Name', 'Email2': 'Email'}, axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

# display(df)
   Status   Name           Email
0  Active    Tom  test@gmail.com
1  Active   John  test@gmail.com
2  Active  krish  test@gmail.com
3  Active    Tim  test@gmail.com
4  Active   Jack  test@gmail.com
5  Active   Lisa  test@gmail.com
```

#### One-liner

```py
# as a single line without creating separate objects for each set of columns
df = pd.concat([df.loc[df.Name.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name', 'Email']],
                (df.loc[df.Name2.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name2', 'Email2']])
                .rename({'Name2': 'Name', 'Email2': 'Email'}, axis=1)]).sort_index()
```

### Comparison

```py
# given df in the op, create a large dataset
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)


def trenton(df):
    return pd.concat([df.loc[df.Name.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name', 'Email']],
                      (df.loc[df.Name2.ne(' '), ['Status', 'Name2', 'Email2']])
                      .rename({'Name2': 'Name', 'Email2': 'Email'}, axis=1)]).sort_index()


def echo(df):
    df["Name"] = (df["Name"] + df["Name2"]).str.strip()
    df["Email"] = (df["Email"] + df["Email2"]).str.strip()
    df = df.drop(["Name2", "Email2"], axis=1)
    return df


def sierra(df):
    df['Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[3] if x[1] == ' ' else x[1], axis=1)
    df['Email'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[4] if x[2] == ' ' else x[2], axis=1)
    df = df.drop(labels=['Name2', 'Email2'], axis=1)
    return df


def BeRT2me(df):
    df = df.applymap(str.strip)
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)
    df.Name = df.Name.fillna(df.Name2)
    df.Email = df.Email.fillna(df.Email2)
    df = df.drop(['Name2', 'Email2'], axis=1)
    return df
```

#### `timeit`

```py
%timeit trenton(df)
[out]:
101 ms ± 604 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit echo(dftest)
[out]:
390 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit sierra(df)
[out]:
6.11 s ± 64.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit BeRT2me(df)
[out]:
258 ms ± 4.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I apply your code to my dataset I get blank rows in between each row. Do you how to avoid this?

Comment: @LeonardoUrbiola does it run with the sample data? It probably means the Boolean indexing isn't matching the pattern for the blank spaces. The description in my answer includes additional measures for matching the blank spaces.

Comment: @LeonardoUrbiola the best way to know for sure is to share an actual example of the dataframe. `print(df.head(10).to_dict('list'))` and then paste that into a code block in your question. This assumes the dataframe has missing spaces in the first 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
df["Name"] = (df["Name"] + df["Name2"]).str.strip() # the strip(), to get rid of any white spaces around values.
df["Email"] = (df["Email"] + df["Email2"]).str.strip()
df.drop(["Name2", "Email2"], axis=1,inplace= True)
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[3] if x[1] == ' ' else x[1], axis=1)
df['Email'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[4] if x[2] == ' ' else x[2], axis=1)
df = df.drop(labels=['Name2', 'Email2'], axis=1)
```

result:

```
   Status   Name           Email
0  Active    Tom  test@gmail.com
1  Active   John  test@gmail.com
2  Active  krish  test@gmail.com
3  Active    Tim  test@gmail.com
4  Active   Jack  test@gmail.com
5  Active   Lisa  test@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
   Status   Name           Email Name2          Email2
0  Active    Tom  test@gmail.com
1  Active                         John  test@gmail.com
2  Active  krish  test@gmail.com
3  Active                          Tim  test@gmail.com
4  Active   Jack  test@gmail.com
5  Active   Lisa  test@gmail.com
```

Doing:

```
# Fix empty strings to be proper nan values:
df = df.applymap(str.strip)
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

# Fill Missing Values:
df.Name = df.Name.fillna(df.Name2)
df.Email = df.Email.fillna(df.Email2)

# Drop Excess columns:
df = df.drop(['Name2', 'Email2'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Status   Name           Email
0  Active    Tom  test@gmail.com
1  Active   John  test@gmail.com
2  Active  krish  test@gmail.com
3  Active    Tim  test@gmail.com
4  Active   Jack  test@gmail.com
5  Active   Lisa  test@gmail.com
```